# How can I get correct transposition matrix by using structure in C?

Tags: c, matrix, structure, transpose

I made this program to get the matrix `a` and matrix `b` that is  a transposition matrix of matrix `a`.

The problem is that I couldn't get an accurate transposition matrix.

I checked the functions several times, but I couldn't find which part was wrong.

And there were no errors when compiling.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    int row;
    int col;
    int value;
} term;
```

I declared the structure **term** that I use throughout my program.

```
void transpose(term a[], term b[])
{
    int n, currentb;
    n = a[0].value; // Total number of elements  
    b[0].row = a[0].col; // Number of rows in b = Number of columns in a 
    b[0].col = a[0].row; // Number of columns in b = Number of rows in a
    b[0].value = n;

    if (n > 0) // A nonzero matrix
    {
        currentb = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < a[0].col; i++) // Starting from the 0th column
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++) // Find the element from the current column
            {
                if (a[j].col == i)
                {
                    // Add the elements in the current column to b.
                    b[currentb].row = a[j].col;
                    b[currentb].col = a[j].row;
                    b[currentb].value = a[j].value;
                    currentb++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

At first, I thought the function above was wrong.

So, I have looked at the logic several times and I couldn't find the wrong part.

```
int main()
{
    term a[3] = { {1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9} }
    term b[3];

    // print term a
    printf("original matrix\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf(" %d %d %d\n", a[i].row, a[i].col, a[i].value);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    
    // call the transpose function
    void transpose(term a[], term b[]);
    
    // print term b
    printf("transpose matrix\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf(" %d %d %d\n", b[i].row, b[i].col, b[i].value);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Next, I reviewed the line that calls the transpose function.

Because the output result was like this:

```
original matrix
 1 2 3
 4 5 6
 7 8 9

transpose matrix
 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460
 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460
 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460
```

I have already searched more than 10 pages of questions, but I haven't found a question that has the same wrong result like mine that uses a structure to get the transposition matrix.

And if there was no problem with the code, the result should have been as follows.

```
original matrix
 1 2 3
 4 5 6
 7 8 9
    
transpose matrix
 1 4 7
 2 5 8
 3 6 9
```

Please check my code, i would appreciate it if you could tell me if there is anything wrong.

Comment: Apart from not understanding what you are trying to achieve with your struct, `void transpose(term a[], term b[]);` is a function prototype, not a function call...

Comment: Could you elaborate how you store matrix? According to the expected output, you wan to store matrix in a 2D array. But if I look at your definition of struct term,  you only want to store non-zero elements and their locations.

Comment: Where did you get the source code from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you represent matrices is inappropriate for the assignment: you use arrays of `term` structures, each with a `row`, `col` and `value` fields. This representation is valid for sparse matrices, and transposing this representation is easy: just swap the `col` and `row` fields of each `term`, but you would need to pass the array length to the `transpose` function as it cannot determine the number of elements from the argument types, values or contents.

Yet the main problem is you are not calling `transpose` at all: `void transpose(term a[], term b[]);` is just a function declaration, not a call. You should write:

```
  // call the transpose function
  transpose(a, b);
```

The example posted suggests you are dealing with simple matrices represented as arrays of arrays. here is a modified version for 3x3 matrices represented as arrays of arrays:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void transpose(int a[3][3], int b[3][3]) {
    if (a == b) {
        // transposing the matrix in place:
        // swap the upper and lower triangles
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                int temp = a[j][i];
                a[j][i] = a[i][j];
                a[i][j] = temp;
            }
        }
    } else {
        // source and destination are distinct
        // copy the elements in transposed order
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                a[i][j] = b[j][i];
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int a[3][3] = { {1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9} }
    int b[3][3];

    // print term a
    printf("original matrix\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf(" %d %d %d\n", a[i][0], a[i][1], a[i][2]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    
    // call the transpose function
    transpose(a, b);
    
    // print term b
    printf("transpose matrix\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf(" %d %d %d\n", b[i][0], b[i][1], b[i][2]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The way is usually used for storing sparse matrix.

Comment: @Zwy: yes, but the example posted by the OP suggests a simpler approach.